# v1 and v2 signature non tickable

Tags: android

I  have a source code of an app while I am trying to generate signed apk .
signature v1 and v2 are non tickable.
means non of it can be checked or non clickable.
can any tell where should I look for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this new signature don't work in some version of gradle so try to update android studio and gradle to fix this problem.

**Android Studio --> 2.3 or above**

**Gradle --> 2.3 or above**

Comment: i have already updated android to 3.1 but I will try gradle to 2.3 because mine is 2.1.3